# Result of | grep in a variable

Tags: ubuntu, shell, script

Here is my script:

```
    var=  $( $line | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)' )
    echo $var
```

I have an error and it only displays:

```
 command not found
```

Have you any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Also, in case anyone is wondering: This is extremely dangerous. If `$line` where to contain `rm -rf /` it would happily proceed destroy your system. Don’t ever execute variables, except perhaps if they only contain your contents and not user/file input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping output of a command to a variable..

A simple example a bit like yours

```
$ a=$(echo abc | grep -o a)

$ echo $a
a
```

So in your case

```
$ line=asdf.fr

$ a=$(echo $line | grep -Po '.*(?=.fr)')

$ echo $a
asdf

$
```

Your line failed because it expanded the line variable $line, and executed it which writes an error to stderr and nothing to stdout.  All the $ with different meanings are a bit funny looking. But if you did(at the prompt of $) `$$line<ENTER>` Then you get command not found. And if you do `$$line>a` `cat a` then you see nothing there. So it's piping nothing to grep and finding nothing. So, you need to echo the line variable, rather than run it like it's a command.